# AciTree load from url just once

Tags: jquery, json, servlets, acitree

Hello I am trying to make a tree from values that is gathered from servlet. these are my code;

```
 $('#hierarchy').aciTree({
        ajax: {
          //  url: 'assets/global/plugins/aciTree/json/checkbox.json'
            method : 'post',
            Url : 'HierarchyServlet'

        },
        // our custom filter/search
        filterHook: function(item, search, regexp) {
            if (search.length) {
                // try to get the parent
                var parent = this.parent(item);
                if (parent.length) {
                    // get parent label
                    var label = this.getLabel(parent);
                    if (regexp.test(String(label))) {
                        // all direct childrens match
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // match the item
                return regexp.test(String(this.getLabel(item)));
            } else {
                // empty search, all matches
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

But when user try to click ( + ) sign it request from servlet again. 
 My question is how not to request again. Because I will send all json at once.

Answer (score 2):

The tree view will make a single ajax request to load his nodes only if you send the entire tree strucure back from the server in this first request.

When I say the entire tree structure, I mean there need not to be any inodes that does not have children. The tree view will try to load an inode if there are no children set, making a new ajax request for that.

What you need to do is to ensure there are no inodes having the `branch` property set to null or empty in the json returned from the server.